# recurrent neural network ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, lstm

I am running an LSTM, GRU and bilstm model using the following code

```
# Create BiLSTM model
def create_model_bilstm(units):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units = units,                             
              return_sequences=True),
              input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    #model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units = units)))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    #Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    return model

# Create LSTM or GRU model
def create_model(units, m):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(m (units = units, return_sequences = True,
                input_shape = [X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]]))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    #model.add(m (units = units))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units = 1))
    #Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    return model

# BiLSTM
model_bilstm = create_model_bilstm(20)

# GRU and LSTM
model_gru = create_model(50, GRU)
model_lstm = create_model(20, LSTM)

# Fit BiLSTM, LSTM and GRU
def fit_model(model):
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss',
                                               patience = 100)
    
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 700,  
                        validation_split = 0.2, batch_size = 32, 
                        shuffle = False, callbacks = [early_stop])
    return history

history_bilstm = fit_model(model_bilstm)
history_lstm = fit_model(model_lstm)
history_gru = fit_model(model_gru)
```

This all runs smoothly and prints out my loss graphs. but when it comes to predictions i run the following code

```
# Make prediction
def prediction(model):
    prediction = model.predict(X_test)
    prediction = scaler_y.inverse_transform(prediction)
    return prediction

prediction_bilstm = prediction(model_bilstm)
prediction_lstm = prediction(model_lstm)
prediction_gru = prediction(model_gru)
```

and i get the following error

```
   ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-387-9d45f01ae2a2> in <module>
      5     return prediction
      6 
----> 7 prediction_bilstm = prediction(model_bilstm)
      8 prediction_lstm = prediction(model_lstm)
      9 prediction_gru = prediction(model_gru)

<ipython-input-387-9d45f01ae2a2> in prediction(model)
      2 def prediction(model):
      3     prediction = model.predict(X_test)
----> 4     prediction = scaler_y.inverse_transform(prediction)
      5     return prediction

                         ...

    ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I am assuming this has something to do with my X_test shape based on other posts i have read so i tried to reshape it to 2d but got another error telling me "expected bidirectional_3_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (62, 36)" on line 7 again.

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Data Explanation:
So I am trying to predict discharge rates (target variable) using groundwater levels (34 features), precipitation and temperature as input which gives me a total of 36 features. My data is in monthly resolution. I am using 63 observation for my test (5 year pred) and the rest for my train.

Comment: can you please tell the shape of **X_test** and **X_train** aswell

Comment: @SrikarManthatti `X_test.shape = (62, 1, 36)` and `X_train = (316, 1, 36)`

Comment: I believe it is surely with the shape of the data since for bilstm you are training with input dimensions (316,1) and while predicting you are passing (62,1,36). May I know on what data you are working on, what does those second(1) and third dimension (36) mean in your data? If it is okay you can paste a picture of data and talk about it.

Comment: @SrikarManthatti i have added an explanation for my data. Based on your comment does this mean my reshape is wrong?

Comment: Great!!! so as per your explanation I suggest that the shape of your X_train should be (316,36), y_train (316,1), and the test should be X_test(63,36) and Y_test should be(63,1)

Comment: @SrikarManthatti but for lstm, gru and bilstm the data is expected to be in 3D is it not? If i make it 2D the models won't accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223026/discussion-between-srikar-manthatti-and-denise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What are you doing wrong?** Let's assume your input data has shape `X_train.shape = [d0,d1,d2]`, then after setting up your BiLSTM-model like

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional,LSTM,Dense

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(
   tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
      tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
         units = 10,                             
         return_sequences=True),
         input_shape=(d1, d2)
         )
      )
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

we can check the input- and output-shapes your model expects by

```
>>model.input.shape
TensorShape([None, d1, d2])
>>model.output.shape
TensorShape([None, d1, 1])
```

So your model expects input of shape `(n_batch,d1,d2)`, where `n_batch` is the batch size of the data, and returns a shape `(n_batch,d1,1)`, thus a **3d**-tensor.

Now if you provide a 3d-tensor to your model, the `model.prediction`-method will succesfully return a 3d-tensor, however `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform` only works for 2d-data, thats why it says

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

On the other hand, if you first reshape your data to be 2d, then `model.prediction` complains, because it is set up to expect a 3d-tensor.

**How can you fix it?** For further help on how to fix your code, you will need to provide us with more detailled information on what you *expect* your model to do, especially what output-shape you want your BiLSTM-model to have. I assume you actually want your BiLSTM-model to return a scalar for each sample, so an additional `Flatten`-layer might do the trick:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional,LSTM,Dense,Flatten

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(
   tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
      tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
         units = 10,                             
         return_sequences=True),
         input_shape=(d1, d2)
         )
      )
model.add(Flatten()) #<-- additional flatten-layer
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```